# Non-Hausdorff compactification of $\mathbb{Z}$ is 1st-countable?

Tags: general-topology, compactification

Let $X$ be as non-Hausdorff compactification of $\mathbb{Z}$ with two points $\infty_1$ and $\infty_2$ such that a basis of neighborhoods of$\infty_i$ is formed by
the sets $U$, $\infty_i\in  U$, with finite complement.

$X$  is a compact non-Hausdorff
space. What can say about the first countability of it.

Is it true that $X$ is first countable?

Please help me to know it.

Comment: What are your thoughts? What have you tried?

Answer (score 3):

$X$ is countable, so it has countably many finite subsets and so the given local base of both $\infty_i$ is countable already. Every point $n$ of $\Bbb Z$ has $\{\{n\}\}$ as a local base (being a discrete space). Draw your conclusions.